# Renamed PyCharm project and directory, how to align with Gitlab

Tags: pycharm, gitlab, project, rename

I was forced to rename a PyCharm project after starting it. It was first created in Gitlab and then tied to the PyCharm project. How can I rename the GitLab project and make the weblink work again?

Answer (score 1):

From the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/settings/#renaming-a-repository):

> To rename a repository:
>
> 1. Navigate to your project's Settings > General > Advanced settings.
> 2. Under "Rename repository", change the "Path" to your liking.
> 3. Hit Rename project.